# React Native Expo can't replace splash screen with custom when fonts are loaded

Tags: react-native, splash-screen, google-fonts

I'm learning to build apps in React Native and I'm using Expo + Android Virtual Device and also testing using the Expo App in my iphone, I'm getting the same problem in both devices.

I'm trying to load a customized SplashScreen, I have already removed the "splash" inside `app.json` and this is my code (I was trying to load the View component first, so I could see it functioning and use Lottie later - I have already tested Lottie animations in other parts of the project and it's already working, so I think it's not related to it)

```
import { Stack } from "expo-router";
import {
  Oxygen_400Regular,
  Oxygen_700Bold,
  useFonts,
} from "@expo-google-fonts/oxygen";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";

const Layout = () => {
  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    Oxygen_400Regular,
    Oxygen_700Bold,
  });

  if (!fontsLoaded)
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <Text>Test</Text>
      </View>
    );

  return <Stack />;
};

export default Layout;
```

The `return <Stack/>` shows my app home page, and it's showing normally after a few seconds. But the View with the Text inside is not loading, instead I get a white screen with no text in it, and then a few seconds later (I suppose when the app fully loads) the Homepage appears normally.

After some console.logs, it seems to me that the fontsLoaded doesn't load until the native Splash Screen finishes loading, and that seems to be the reason why fontsLoaded is not returning false in any moment.

I think I may be doing something wrong, would really appreciate any advices.

I have tried a bunch of solutions:

- npm dedupe
- expo upgrade
- something like this, suggested by chatgpt:

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Image, View } from "react-native";
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
import { Oxygen_400Regular, Oxygen_700Bold } from "@expo-google-fonts/oxygen";

const SplashScreen = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <Text> test</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const Layout = () => {
  const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    Oxygen_400Regular,
    Oxygen_700Bold,
  });

  const [showSplash, setShowSplash] = useState(true);

  const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
    if (fontsLoaded) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setShowSplash(false);
      }, 1000);
    }
  }, [fontsLoaded]);

  useEffect(() => {
    onLayoutRootView();
  }, []);

  if (showSplash) {
    return <SplashScreen />;
  }

  return <Stack/>;
};

export default Layout;
```

- None of the above worked, and got the same problem everytime, a white screen that behaves like a splash screen, but doesn't show my custom component